# Close to end of the page, element needs to disappear

Tags: jquery, css

I have this JS code that I use to add and remove a class while scrolling down from the top of a page, but what I want is to do is also disappear when you come close to the end of the page or go back to its old state after some scrolling (from right: 7px to right: -150px, for example). I copied the same JS code and changed the `scrollTop > scrollBottom` and it didn't work.

```js
jQuery(document).on('scroll', (e) => {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 120 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350) {
    console.log('now');
    jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').addClass('filterr');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
    jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').removeClass('filterr');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh
}

.ast-below-header-bar {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  right: -150px;
  top: 14%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.ast-below-header-bar.filterr {
  right: 7px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ast-below-header-bar"></div>
```

Comment: Surely it's just a matter of adjusting your `document.body.scrollTop > 120 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350` statement to select the range where you want the element to be shown? (E.g. `scrollTop > 120 && scrollTop < 400`)

Comment: @DBS this works from top scrolling but i want it also disappear when it come close to bottom of the page with same way but scrollTop only works for top scrolling. Thats the problem

Comment: If you want to work out the distance from the bottom, you can do something like: [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) - scrollTop (Make sure to read the "Problems and solutions" section on that page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `window.innerHeight` to perform the calculation on the bottom of your scroll.

Adjust it according to your needs.

```js
jQuery(document).on('scroll', (e) => {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset + 350) <= document.body.offsetHeight && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 350) {
    console.log('now');
    jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').addClass('filterr');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
    jQuery('.ast-below-header-bar').removeClass('filterr');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 500vh
}

.ast-below-header-bar {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  right: -150px;
  top: 14%;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.ast-below-header-bar.filterr {
  right: 7px!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ast-below-header-bar"></div>
```